# openssl 'ml64' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: openssl

I'm a newbie on openssl and I'm struggling to install openssl on Windows 7 64bits system. I've a trouble on 'ml64'. As I mentioned on the title, It just pops up on a command line that 'ml64' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

First, I installed Visual studio community 2015 but there were no 'nmake' and 'ml64' so I've downloaded visual studio 2010 professional. It has 'nmake' and 'ml64'. So I add these to system path. It still doesn't work though. ['ml64' is not recognized as an internal or external command] this problem still occures.

I have totally no idea what I have to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: try downloading these driver packs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx
AND
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=12654

Comment: If you only want to install and **use** OpenSSL and don't need your own build (e.g. if you want to change the code), the prebuilt packages from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html are free-beer (but donation suggested) and "just work" with MSI, startmenu, etc. (Don't be misled by the "Win32" in the name, they have both 32bit and 64bit versions. Plus OpenSSL is all userland, so you can run 32-bit OpenSSL on 64-bit Windows if you want.)

Answer (score 5):

in "***C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2015\Visual Studio Tools\Windows Desktop Command Prompts***", use "***VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt***" to launch your command prompts.

and you will find ***ml64*** is available.

Answer (score 2):

With Visual Studio 2019, run from the command prompt called `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` that you will find under `start menu/visual studio 2019`. This command prompt has the paths set up correctly to compile `OpenSSL` (the "developer command prompt for VS2019" doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

That error scrolls by when I build openssl, but the build ultimately completes.  I'm not entirely sure what it means, but I'll post my build script in case it contains some magic that helps:

```
# buildOpenSSL.ps1
param ( [string]$OpenSSLRoot = "C:\usr\local\OpenSSL" )  
pushd openssl

perl Configure debug-VC-WIN64A --prefix=$OpenSSLRoot
ms\do_win64a

cmd /c "`"${env:VS140COMNTOOLS}../../VC/vcvarsall.bat`" amd64 && nmake /f 
ms\nt.mak && nmake /f ms\nt.mak install"

popd
```

For this to work I install [strawberry perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), and the [visual cpp build tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).  The [openssl source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) lives in a directory called `openssl` which I added to my project as a submodule (but you could just clone it too).

If I recall, NASM was required for the 32 bit build, but ever since we switched to 64 bit, I haven't needed to install it.  Recently completed on Windows Server 2016 against OpenSSL build 1.0.2j